# how to remove white space content between the bullet symbol and the paragraph using OpenXML

Tags: c#, list, openxml, space, numbered

I'm creating a word document using c# and OpenXML. In the document I have several bulleted lists, My question is how to change the size of or remove the white space content between the bullet symbol and the paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found it, I had to add LevelSuffix element into my Level element, Like this :

```
var a = new AbstractNum(
                                new Nsid() { Val = "FFFFFF80" }
                                , new MultiLevelType() { Val = MultiLevelValues.HybridMultilevel }
                                , new Level(
                                  new LevelSuffix { Val = LevelSuffixValues.Space, },
                                  new NumberingFormat() { Val = NumberFormatValues.Bullet },
                                  new LevelText() { Val = "-" }
                                ) { LevelIndex = 0 }
                              ) { AbstractNumberId = abstarctnumberId };
```

I also found [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee922775%28v=office.14%29.aspx) very useful.